# Python:how to input the file name in python

Tags: python

im very new to python.
when I do `fileofname = "a2.txt"`
then i can run my code without any problem
However,when I do `fileofname = raw_input("enter the file name:")`
then i type "a2.txt"
and it raises a `"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'line' referenced before assignment"`

Can someone help me??

Comment: You need to show the actual code that you're having problems with if you want any useful help.

Comment: Please add more of your script to your question.  The error message says you tried to use a local variable called `line` but you did not show where in your script this usage occurred.

Comment: Plese try to add some details. Your error, however, seem to sa us that you don't assign any value at variable called `line` so, input isn't the problem (without any other snippet of code)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to read a CSV file

```
import csv
import os

ifilename = raw_input('Enter a file name: ')
ifile  = open(ifilename, "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
for row in reader:
     .......
     .........
     ..........
```

if you need to read a txt file:

```
import os

print "Enter a file name:",
filename = raw_input()
```

OR

```
filename = raw_input('Enter a file name: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fileofname = raw_input("enter the file name:")
fileObject = open(fileofname, 'r')
for line in fileObject:
    print line
```